# Getting error using 'belongs_to' in Ecto phoenix.gen.html

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm making an model that I want to create in relationship to my user model. Following from http://www.phoenixframework.org/v0.13.1/docs/ecto-models#section-data-relationship-and-dependencies used the phoenix.gen.html as follows:

```
W:runcible>mix phoenix.gen.html Ansible ansibles ansible_name:string ansible_description:text user:belongs_to
```

But I Get the following when i run it.

```
Compiled web/models/user.ex
Compiled web/controllers/user_controller.ex
Generated runcible app
** (Mix) Unknown type `belongs_to` given to generator
```

Any ideas where I've made a mistake?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are looking at an old version (0.13) of the documentation.

As of Phoenix 0.16 It should be:

```
mix phoenix.gen.model Video videos name:string approved_at:datetime description:text likes:integer views:integer user_id:references:users
```

Note:

```
user_id:references:users
```

instead of:

```
user:belongs_to
```

Here is a link to the [latest docs](http://www.phoenixframework.org/v1.0.0/docs/ecto-models#section-data-relationship-and-dependencies).

Comment: Thank again Gazler. My Google searching led me to the older docs.